# Is burp suite worked for android native application?

Tags: android, burp

Is burp suite works for android native application? if yes then how ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes burp can be used with android native applications. you can intercept the traffic of your android phone using burp but for that you have to configure burp to be used with android device by following this tutorial,

https://support.portswigger.net/customer/portal/articles/1841101-configuring-an-android-device-to-work-with-burp

Comment: Thank you  @Darshan , I have configure it but it has not worked for native application where as through web it is working fine .